# PROGMEM array consuming RAM

Tags: arduino

I have defined (globally) a large array of strings thus:

```
const String opCodes[256]PROGMEM = {""...""}; // all 256 defined
```

However, building this now consumes 20% more RAM than it did before I added the array.

This was unexpected. Why did it happen? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Arduino `String` object](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) is a dynamic string much like `std::string`. And as such stores its data in dynamically allocated memory in RAM.

If you want to store the actual string data itself in `PROGMEM` then the [Arduino `PROGMEM` reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/) will tell you how do do it using actual arrays of characters instead. In short, create arrays of characters stored in `PROGMEM`, and then make an array of `const char *` (also in `PROGMEM`) pointing to the strings.

Comment: Thanks you. I followed the instructions in the Arduino reference you gave, but it still consumes an extra 20% of RAM when compiled.

Comment: For comparison, here are the memory stats for 3 cases - no string array, RAM-based and PROGMEM-based:

Comment: // NONE
//Program size : 25, 064 bytes(used 10 % of a 253, 952 byte maximum) (4.03 secs)
//Minimum Memory Usage : 4391 bytes(54 % of a 8192 byte maximum)

// RAM
//Program size : 28, 452 bytes(used 11 % of a 253, 952 byte maximum) (4.20 secs)
//Minimum Memory Usage : 6213 bytes(76 % of a 8192 byte maximum)

// PROGMEM
//Program size : 28, 452 bytes(used 11 % of a 253, 952 byte maximum) (4.27 secs)
//Minimum Memory Usage : 5927 bytes(72 % of a 8192 byte maximum)

Comment: Further - removing the array, and just looking at a dozen strings, the memory consumption is identical for both RAM and PROGMEM based versions, so it seems the compiler is ignoring the PROGMEM directive: //Program size : 25, 064 bytes(used 10 % of a 253, 952 byte maximum) (4.03 secs)
//Minimum Memory Usage : 4391 bytes(54 % of a 8192 byte maximum)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided not to use `PROGMEM` as its use seems a bit suspect.

A usable workaround was to use the `F()` function instead. This works.